# Are these objects functionally equal?

Tags: c#, initialization, declaration, assign

I am creating a context menu for a form button, I came across this way of implementing it and it was different than I had expected. Could I get an explanation of any differences between the two if there is any?

The way I thought it worked:

```
private void InitializeContextMenu()
{
    System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip set_is_in_inventory = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip();
}

private System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip set_is_in_inventory;
```

The way I found on msdn:

```
private void InitializeContextMenu()
{
    set_is_in_inventory = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip();
    this.ContextMenuStrip = set_is_in_inventory;
}

private System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip set_is_in_inventory;
```

Comment: MSDN is assigning it to the form so it will actually appear, all you do is create the object. Perahps you could explain *why* you thought your way would work and we can answer the more fundamental misunderstanding?

Comment: And as an aside, now's a good time to become familiar with .NET naming conventions and start following them.

Comment: The first version is odd. You have a local and a private field by the same name. You never use (AFAICT) the private field. The name is coincidental. You're declaring two distinct references that are not the same reference. Also what JS says about naming conventions. `_setIsInInventory` is the convention.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET : I thought that the last statement is a notification to the compiler that such an item will exist, and the wrapper function actually created it. In the second example, it appears to assign the item to a type. ( I was just taught C, so my vocabulary may be lacking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first version, you've instantiated a new variable in `InitializeContextMenu()` called `set_is_in_inventory` which has type `ContextMenuStrip`, which, as the commenters have pointed out, should probably be named to `_setIsInInventory` to follow .NET naming conventions. Anyways. You're not actually using this variable anywhere. It has no scope outside of the method and it does nothing. What I think you want is to set the *property* of the class. To make the classes' `set_is_in_inventory` property to be the one you just instantiated, you need to do

```
private void InitializeContextMenu(){
{
    this.set_is_in_inventory = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip();
}
```

or optionally,

```
set_is_in_inventory = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip();
```

which is the first line in the MSDN example. What may be confusing you as well in the MSDN example is that it looks like the class has another property called `ContextMenuStrip` that is also being set in the **second line**. This is also being set to `set_is_in_inventory`. Sometimes class properties have their name as the name of the class, like so (perfectly legal syntax):

```
public ClassA {
    public Class Class {get;set;}
}
```

To set `ClassA's` *property* `Class`, you just do

```
this.Class = new Class();
```

or

```
Class = new Class();
```

You can see how this can be confusing so a lot of people just name the property different from the class name, like this:

```
public ClassA{
    public Class MyClass {get;set;}
}
```

HTH.

Comment: My pleasure. Please accept this if it answered your question.